# For a vector field $\textbf{F} = xy\textbf{i} + x²\textbf{j} + z²\textbf{k}$ , find the magnitude and direction of the vector at $(0,1,1)$

Tags: calculus

For a vector field $\textbf{F} = xy\textbf{i} + x²\textbf{j} + z²\textbf{k}$ , find the magnitude and direction of the vector at $(0,1,1)$.

Here's what I did:
Magnitude = $\sqrt{0^2 + 1^2 + 1^2} = \sqrt{2}$

Angle $\theta$ = $\frac{\left<0,1,1\right>}{\sqrt{0^2+1^2+1^2}}=\left<0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right>$ (then solve using cos/sin depending which axis you want the angle from etc).

But I think this is wrong, it doesn't have anything to do with the vector $\textbf{F} = xy\textbf{i} + x²\textbf{j} + z²\textbf{k}$.

Comment: You have to substitute the coordinates into vector field first.

Answer (score 1):

Vecorfield has value $F=<0,0,1>$ at point $(0,1,1)$.

Magnitude is therefore 1 and direction is z-axis.